# Get latitude/longitude coords when I have Country name/ISO with Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, country-codes

In Android I have the countrys ISO code.
I want to get the latitude/longitude coordinates from that country.

I am using the Google Maps API.

How can I get the coordinates?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK there is no API in Google Maps for that.

But you can use this: https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv

You can create HashMap with these values.

```
Map<String, LatLng> countries = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();

countries.put("PL", new LatLng(51.919438, 19.145136));
```

Later you can use it like this:

```
countries.get("PL"); // returns LatLng(51.919438, 19.145136)
```

Also converted the full list for anyone who wants it:

```
public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> COUNTRY_ISOS = new HashMap<String, LatLng>() {{
    put("AD", new LatLng(42.546245,1.601554));
    put("AE", new LatLng(23.424076,53.847818));
    put("AF", new LatLng(33.93911,67.709953));
    put("AG", new LatLng(17.060816,-61.796428));
    put("AI", new LatLng(18.220554,-63.068615));
    put("AL", new LatLng(41.153332,20.168331));
    put("AM", new LatLng(40.069099,45.038189));
    put("AN", new LatLng(12.226079,-69.060087));
    put("AO", new LatLng(-11.202692,17.873887));
    put("AQ", new LatLng(-75.250973,-0.071389));
    put("AR", new LatLng(-38.416097,-63.616672));
    put("AS", new LatLng(-14.270972,-170.132217));
    put("AT", new LatLng(47.516231,14.550072));
    put("AU", new LatLng(-25.274398,133.775136));
    put("AW", new LatLng(12.52111,-69.968338));
    put("AZ", new LatLng(40.143105,47.576927));
    put("BA", new LatLng(43.915886,17.679076));
    put("BB", new LatLng(13.193887,-59.543198));
    put("BD", new LatLng(23.684994,90.356331));
    put("BE", new LatLng(50.503887,4.469936));
    put("BF", new LatLng(12.238333,-1.561593));
    put("BG", new LatLng(42.733883,25.48583));
    put("BH", new LatLng(25.930414,50.637772));
    put("BI", new LatLng(-3.373056,29.918886));
    put("BJ", new LatLng(9.30769,2.315834));
    put("BM", new LatLng(32.321384,-64.75737));
    put("BN", new LatLng(4.535277,114.727669));
    put("BO", new LatLng(-16.290154,-63.588653));
    put("BR", new LatLng(-14.235004,-51.92528));
    put("BS", new LatLng(25.03428,-77.39628));
    put("BT", new LatLng(27.514162,90.433601));
    put("BV", new LatLng(-54.423199,3.413194));
    put("BW", new LatLng(-22.328474,24.684866));
    put("BY", new LatLng(53.709807,27.953389));
    put("BZ", new LatLng(17.189877,-88.49765));
    put("CA", new LatLng(56.130366,-106.346771));
    put("CC", new LatLng(-12.164165,96.870956));
    put("CD", new LatLng(-4.038333,21.758664));
    put("CF", new LatLng(6.611111,20.939444));
    put("CG", new LatLng(-0.228021,15.827659));
    put("CH", new LatLng(46.818188,8.227512));
    put("CI", new LatLng(7.539989,-5.54708));
    put("CK", new LatLng(-21.236736,-159.777671));
    put("CL", new LatLng(-35.675147,-71.542969));
    put("CM", new LatLng(7.369722,12.354722));
    put("CN", new LatLng(35.86166,104.195397));
    put("CO", new LatLng(4.570868,-74.297333));
    put("CR", new LatLng(9.748917,-83.753428));
    put("CU", new LatLng(21.521757,-77.781167));
    put("CV", new LatLng(16.002082,-24.013197));
    put("CX", new LatLng(-10.447525,105.690449));
    put("CY", new LatLng(35.126413,33.429859));
    put("CZ", new LatLng(49.817492,15.472962));
    put("DE", new LatLng(51.165691,10.451526));
    put("DJ", new LatLng(11.825138,42.590275));
    put("DK", new LatLng(56.26392,9.501785));
    put("DM", new LatLng(15.414999,-61.370976));
    put("DO", new LatLng(18.735693,-70.162651));
    put("DZ", new LatLng(28.033886,1.659626));
    put("EC", new LatLng(-1.831239,-78.183406));
    put("EE", new LatLng(58.595272,25.013607));
    put("EG", new LatLng(26.820553,30.802498));
    put("EH", new LatLng(24.215527,-12.885834));
    put("ER", new LatLng(15.179384,39.782334));
    put("ES", new LatLng(40.463667,-3.74922));
    put("ET", new LatLng(9.145,40.489673));
    put("FI", new LatLng(61.92411,25.748151));
    put("FJ", new LatLng(-16.578193,179.414413));
    put("FK", new LatLng(-51.796253,-59.523613));
    put("FM", new LatLng(7.425554,150.550812));
    put("FO", new LatLng(61.892635,-6.911806));
    put("FR", new LatLng(46.227638,2.213749));
    put("GA", new LatLng(-0.803689,11.609444));
    put("GB", new LatLng(55.378051,-3.435973));
    put("GD", new LatLng(12.262776,-61.604171));
    put("GE", new LatLng(42.315407,43.356892));
    put("GF", new LatLng(3.933889,-53.125782));
    put("GG", new LatLng(49.465691,-2.585278));
    put("GH", new LatLng(7.946527,-1.023194));
    put("GI", new LatLng(36.137741,-5.345374));
    put("GL", new LatLng(71.706936,-42.604303));
    put("GM", new LatLng(13.443182,-15.310139));
    put("GN", new LatLng(9.945587,-9.696645));
    put("GP", new LatLng(16.995971,-62.067641));
    put("GQ", new LatLng(1.650801,10.267895));
    put("GR", new LatLng(39.074208,21.824312));
    put("GS", new LatLng(-54.429579,-36.587909));
    put("GT", new LatLng(15.783471,-90.230759));
    put("GU", new LatLng(13.444304,144.793731));
    put("GW", new LatLng(11.803749,-15.180413));
    put("GY", new LatLng(4.860416,-58.93018));
    put("GZ", new LatLng(31.354676,34.308825));
    put("HK", new LatLng(22.396428,114.109497));
    put("HM", new LatLng(-53.08181,73.504158));
    put("HN", new LatLng(15.199999,-86.241905));
    put("HR", new LatLng(45.1,15.2));
    put("HT", new LatLng(18.971187,-72.285215));
    put("HU", new LatLng(47.162494,19.503304));
    put("ID", new LatLng(-0.789275,113.921327));
    put("IE", new LatLng(53.41291,-8.24389));
    put("IL", new LatLng(31.046051,34.851612));
    put("IM", new LatLng(54.236107,-4.548056));
    put("IN", new LatLng(20.593684,78.96288));
    put("IO", new LatLng(-6.343194,71.876519));
    put("IQ", new LatLng(33.223191,43.679291));
    put("IR", new LatLng(32.427908,53.688046));
    put("IS", new LatLng(64.963051,-19.020835));
    put("IT", new LatLng(41.87194,12.56738));
    put("JE", new LatLng(49.214439,-2.13125));
    put("JM", new LatLng(18.109581,-77.297508));
    put("JO", new LatLng(30.585164,36.238414));
    put("JP", new LatLng(36.204824,138.252924));
    put("KE", new LatLng(-0.023559,37.906193));
    put("KG", new LatLng(41.20438,74.766098));
    put("KH", new LatLng(12.565679,104.990963));
    put("KI", new LatLng(-3.370417,-168.734039));
    put("KM", new LatLng(-11.875001,43.872219));
    put("KN", new LatLng(17.357822,-62.782998));
    put("KP", new LatLng(40.339852,127.510093));
    put("KR", new LatLng(35.907757,127.766922));
    put("KW", new LatLng(29.31166,47.481766));
    put("KY", new LatLng(19.513469,-80.566956));
    put("KZ", new LatLng(48.019573,66.923684));
    put("LA", new LatLng(19.85627,102.495496));
    put("LB", new LatLng(33.854721,35.862285));
    put("LC", new LatLng(13.909444,-60.978893));
    put("LI", new LatLng(47.166,9.555373));
    put("LK", new LatLng(7.873054,80.771797));
    put("LR", new LatLng(6.428055,-9.429499));
    put("LS", new LatLng(-29.609988,28.233608));
    put("LT", new LatLng(55.169438,23.881275));
    put("LU", new LatLng(49.815273,6.129583));
    put("LV", new LatLng(56.879635,24.603189));
    put("LY", new LatLng(26.3351,17.228331));
    put("MA", new LatLng(31.791702,-7.09262));
    put("MC", new LatLng(43.750298,7.412841));
    put("MD", new LatLng(47.411631,28.369885));
    put("ME", new LatLng(42.708678,19.37439));
    put("MG", new LatLng(-18.766947,46.869107));
    put("MH", new LatLng(7.131474,171.184478));
    put("MK", new LatLng(41.608635,21.745275));
    put("ML", new LatLng(17.570692,-3.996166));
    put("MM", new LatLng(21.913965,95.956223));
    put("MN", new LatLng(46.862496,103.846656));
    put("MO", new LatLng(22.198745,113.543873));
    put("MP", new LatLng(17.33083,145.38469));
    put("MQ", new LatLng(14.641528,-61.024174));
    put("MR", new LatLng(21.00789,-10.940835));
    put("MS", new LatLng(16.742498,-62.187366));
    put("MT", new LatLng(35.937496,14.375416));
    put("MU", new LatLng(-20.348404,57.552152));
    put("MV", new LatLng(3.202778,73.22068));
    put("MW", new LatLng(-13.254308,34.301525));
    put("MX", new LatLng(23.634501,-102.552784));
    put("MY", new LatLng(4.210484,101.975766));
    put("MZ", new LatLng(-18.665695,35.529562));
    put("NA", new LatLng(-22.95764,18.49041));
    put("NC", new LatLng(-20.904305,165.618042));
    put("NE", new LatLng(17.607789,8.081666));
    put("NF", new LatLng(-29.040835,167.954712));
    put("NG", new LatLng(9.081999,8.675277));
    put("NI", new LatLng(12.865416,-85.207229));
    put("NL", new LatLng(52.132633,5.291266));
    put("NO", new LatLng(60.472024,8.468946));
    put("NP", new LatLng(28.394857,84.124008));
    put("NR", new LatLng(-0.522778,166.931503));
    put("NU", new LatLng(-19.054445,-169.867233));
    put("NZ", new LatLng(-40.900557,174.885971));
    put("OM", new LatLng(21.512583,55.923255));
    put("PA", new LatLng(8.537981,-80.782127));
    put("PE", new LatLng(-9.189967,-75.015152));
    put("PF", new LatLng(-17.679742,-149.406843));
    put("PG", new LatLng(-6.314993,143.95555));
    put("PH", new LatLng(12.879721,121.774017));
    put("PK", new LatLng(30.375321,69.345116));
    put("PL", new LatLng(51.919438,19.145136));
    put("PM", new LatLng(46.941936,-56.27111));
    put("PN", new LatLng(-24.703615,-127.439308));
    put("PR", new LatLng(18.220833,-66.590149));
    put("PS", new LatLng(31.952162,35.233154));
    put("PT", new LatLng(39.399872,-8.224454));
    put("PW", new LatLng(7.51498,134.58252));
    put("PY", new LatLng(-23.442503,-58.443832));
    put("QA", new LatLng(25.354826,51.183884));
    put("RE", new LatLng(-21.115141,55.536384));
    put("RO", new LatLng(45.943161,24.96676));
    put("RS", new LatLng(44.016521,21.005859));
    put("RU", new LatLng(61.52401,105.318756));
    put("RW", new LatLng(-1.940278,29.873888));
    put("SA", new LatLng(23.885942,45.079162));
    put("SB", new LatLng(-9.64571,160.156194));
    put("SC", new LatLng(-4.679574,55.491977));
    put("SD", new LatLng(12.862807,30.217636));
    put("SE", new LatLng(60.128161,18.643501));
    put("SG", new LatLng(1.352083,103.819836));
    put("SH", new LatLng(-24.143474,-10.030696));
    put("SI", new LatLng(46.151241,14.995463));
    put("SJ", new LatLng(77.553604,23.670272));
    put("SK", new LatLng(48.669026,19.699024));
    put("SL", new LatLng(8.460555,-11.779889));
    put("SM", new LatLng(43.94236,12.457777));
    put("SN", new LatLng(14.497401,-14.452362));
    put("SO", new LatLng(5.152149,46.199616));
    put("SR", new LatLng(3.919305,-56.027783));
    put("ST", new LatLng(0.18636,6.613081));
    put("SV", new LatLng(13.794185,-88.89653));
    put("SY", new LatLng(34.802075,38.996815));
    put("SZ", new LatLng(-26.522503,31.465866));
    put("TC", new LatLng(21.694025,-71.797928));
    put("TD", new LatLng(15.454166,18.732207));
    put("TF", new LatLng(-49.280366,69.348557));
    put("TG", new LatLng(8.619543,0.824782));
    put("TH", new LatLng(15.870032,100.992541));
    put("TJ", new LatLng(38.861034,71.276093));
    put("TK", new LatLng(-8.967363,-171.855881));
    put("TL", new LatLng(-8.874217,125.727539));
    put("TM", new LatLng(38.969719,59.556278));
    put("TN", new LatLng(33.886917,9.537499));
    put("TO", new LatLng(-21.178986,-175.198242));
    put("TR", new LatLng(38.963745,35.243322));
    put("TT", new LatLng(10.691803,-61.222503));
    put("TV", new LatLng(-7.109535,177.64933));
    put("TW", new LatLng(23.69781,120.960515));
    put("TZ", new LatLng(-6.369028,34.888822));
    put("UA", new LatLng(48.379433,31.16558));
    put("UG", new LatLng(1.373333,32.290275));
    put("US", new LatLng(37.09024,-95.712891));
    put("UY", new LatLng(-32.522779,-55.765835));
    put("UZ", new LatLng(41.377491,64.585262));
    put("VA", new LatLng(41.902916,12.453389));
    put("VC", new LatLng(12.984305,-61.287228));
    put("VE", new LatLng(6.42375,-66.58973));
    put("VG", new LatLng(18.420695,-64.639968));
    put("VI", new LatLng(18.335765,-64.896335));
    put("VN", new LatLng(14.058324,108.277199));
    put("VU", new LatLng(-15.376706,166.959158));
    put("WF", new LatLng(-13.768752,-177.156097));
    put("WS", new LatLng(-13.759029,-172.104629));
    put("XK", new LatLng(42.602636,20.902977));
    put("YE", new LatLng(15.552727,48.516388));
    put("YT", new LatLng(-12.8275,45.166244));
    put("ZA", new LatLng(-30.559482,22.937506));
    put("ZM", new LatLng(-13.133897,27.849332));
    put("ZW", new LatLng(-19.015438,29.154857));
}};
```

Comment: But how should the url query look like if I only have the country code?

Comment: countries.get(yourISOCode);?

Comment: No, I mean by the url request like 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?country=DE'
for example

Comment: Url you have provided is for geocoder which does not support country iso codes. You need to embed information about country coordinates on your own server or in your map using for example hashmap (see my answer)